# Ion-virtual-scroll inside custom component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular7, ionic4

I'm trying to abstract `ion-virtual-scroll` inside a custom component, along with a lot of other code. I need the `ion-virtual-scroll` to loop over some other custom component. Here's an example of the code before abstraction:

```
<ion-virtual-scroll 
  approxItemHeight="414px"
  [trackBy]="trackBy"
  [items]="items">
  <div *virtualItem="let item">
    <some-other-custom-component [someInput]="item"></some-other-custom-component> 
  </div>
</ion-virtual-scroll>
```

This works great, but I need to feed `some-other-custom-component` into the `custom-component` like this:

```
<custom-component>
  <some-other-custom-component [someInput]="item"></some-other-custom-component>
</custom-component>
```

The only way I've gotten close to doing this is like this (inside custom-component.html):

```
<ion-virtual-scroll  
  [approxItemHeight]="approxItemHeight"
  [trackBy]="trackBy"
  [items]="items">
  <div *virtualItem="let item">
     <ng-content>
     </ng-content>
  </div>
</ion-virtual-scroll>
```

But obviously this won't work because you can't loop an ng-content. Any ideas how to do this or if this is possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We are doing something similar in our project. After a lot of struggling I finally came by a way of doing it. You can use *ngTemplateOutlet* on a *TemplateRef* inside of your custom-component.

In the end it would look something like this:

custom-component.html:

```html
<ion-virtual-scroll  
  [approxItemHeight]="approxItemHeight"
  [trackBy]="trackBy"
  [items]="items"
>
  <div *virtualItem="let item; let idx = index">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="itemTemplate; context: { $implicit: item, index: idx }"> </ng-container>
  </div>
</ion-virtual-scroll>
```

custom-component.ts:

```ts
export class CustomComponent {
  @ContentChild(VirtualItemDirective, { static: false, read: TemplateRef }) 
    itemTemplate: TemplateRef<{
      $implicit: any;
      index: number;
  }>;

  ...
}
```

The VirtualItemDirective's only purpose is to work like the virtual scroll's **virtualItem**.

virtual-item.directive.ts:

```ts
@Directive({ selector: '[appVirtualItem]' })
export class VirtualItemDirective {}
```

And then, finally, the final implementation would be like this:

```html
<custom-component>
  <some-other-custom-component 
    *appVirtualItem="let item; let idx = index" 
    [someInput]="item">
  </some-other-custom-component>
</custom-component>
```

Just some final notes about it, although it works, apparently there's some issues with the initial render. The order seems to be out of place, and I couldn't find a way around that yet.